# How do i show that argument is continuous at points except its branch cut?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $Arg(z)$ be the principal value of argument of $z$, so that $Arg:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow (-\pi,\pi]$ is a function.

How do I prove that $Arg$ is continuous at $z$ for all nonnegative and nonzero $z$?

Comment: Hint: $\arctan$ is continuous. You'll need to do some patching.

Comment: @Ted would you please give me some more hints? I have tried this more than an hour, but still haven't proved anything.. It's geometrically trivial, but I don't know how to actually prove it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $z = x + iy$,
$$   
Arg(z) = \begin{cases} 
\arctan(\frac{y}{x}) &x>0  \\ 
\frac{\pi}{2}  & x = 0, \ y>0 \\ 
-\frac{\pi}{2}  & x = 0, \ y<0 \\
\pi +\arctan(\frac{y}{x})   & x < 0, \ y<0 \\
-\pi -\arctan(\frac{y}{x})   & x < 0, \ y>0 \end{cases}
$$

It's undefined for $z = 0$. 
We will prove continuity for $Arg(z)$, for the first case, $(x>0)$

In order to prove continuity at a point $z$ you must prove the following
$$
\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}Arg(z + \Delta z) - Arg(z) = 0  
$$
Where $\Delta z = \Delta x + i\Delta y$
Using the arctangent definition for $x>0$,

$$
Arg(z + \Delta z) - Arg(z) = \arctan\left(\frac{y + \Delta y}{x + \Delta x}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)
$$

Now using the fact that $arctan$ is an odd function,

$$
- \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) = \arctan\left(-\frac{y}{x}\right)
$$

And the [arctangent additon formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Arctangent_addition_formula), with a little bit of algebra you get
$$
\arctan\left(\frac{y + \Delta y}{x + \Delta x}\right) + \arctan\left(-\frac{y}{x}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{x\Delta y  - y\Delta x}{x^2 + y^2 + x\Delta x + y\Delta y}\right)
$$

When $\Delta z \to 0$, both $\Delta x \to 0$ and $\Delta y \to 0$ so 
$$
\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}Arg(z + \Delta z) - Arg(z) = \lim_{\Delta z\to 0} \arctan\left(\frac{x\Delta y  - y\Delta x}{x^2 + y^2 + x\Delta x + y\Delta y}\right) = 0   
$$

Comment: Is $Arg$ also differentiable at nonnegative nozero points?

Comment: No, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484211/prove-that-fz-arg-z-is-not-analytic-on-d

Comment: @valadimirm Thank you very much!

Comment: It certainly is a smooth (infinitely differentiable) function, but it is not holomorphic (complex differentiable).