# Is the principal value of Argument differentiable at every nonnegative nonzero number?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

[How do i show that argument is continuous at points except its branch cut?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/929653/44669)

I posted a question to ask whether the principal value of Argument $Arg:\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}\rightarrow (-\pi,\pi]$ is continuous at every nonnegative nonzero number.

Then, vladimirm answered my question so now I'm checking his argument.

However, I'm not sure that whether the function $Arg$ is differentiable at every nonnegative nonzero number.

Is it differentiable? Then how do i prove it?

Comment: Do you mean complex of real differentiable?

Comment: I mean complex-differentiablity

Comment: Then, no, it is not complex-differentiable. If a function $f=u+iv$ has $v$ constant and $u$ nonconstant, it cannot be complex-differentiable.

Comment: @Pedro Oh.. since CR doesn't hold right.. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula
$$\tan{\theta\over2}={\sin\theta\over 1+\cos\theta}={y\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}\qquad(-\pi<\theta<\pi)$$
allows to write the principal value of the argument in the form
$${\rm Arg}(x,y)=2\arctan{y\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}$$
(note that the denominator is nonzero in the considered domain $\Omega$). Since the right hand side has continuous partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ on $\Omega$ it follows that ${\rm Arg}$ is indeed differentiable on $\Omega$.

Its worthwhile to memorize the following formula:
$$\nabla{\rm arg}(x,y)=\left({-y\over x^2+y^2}, {x\over x^2+y^2}\right)\ ,$$
which  is valid in the full punctured plane.

Comment: So $Arg$ is not differentiable? It's now clear that it is continuous but I dunno why it's trivial to determine its differentiability

Comment: what is $\Omega$ here? It is, perhaps, the punctured plane for all $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ such that $\theta\neq\pi$?

Comment: @Masacroso: $\Omega$ is the complex plane with the negative real axis together with the origin removed.